# Powershell displaying key against value using select-property

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am using additionalProperties in swagger because of which I am getting the output in the below format in powershell:

```
Path:         ABC
Keys:         {KeyX, KeyY}
Values:       {ValueOfX, ValueOfY}
Count:        2
...
```

Is there any way that this can be displayed as:

```
Path:         ABC
KeyX:         ValueOfX
KeyY:         ValueOfY
```

For expanding the additional properties this is what has been used:

```
$Properties = $obj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AdditionalProperties
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `[ordered]` dictionary to hold the property entries, populate it by correlating the `Keys` and `Values` items by index, and then convert the dictionary to an object:

```
# Create dictionary, add `Path` property entry
$newObjectProperties = [ordered]@{
  Path = $additionalProperties.Path
}

# Correlate Key-Value pairs by index, add to dictionary
for($i = 0; $i -lt $additionalProperties.Count; $i++){
  $newObjectProperties[$additionalProperties.Keys[$i]] = $additionalProperties.Values[$i]
}

# Convert dictionary to an object
$finalObject = [PSCustomObject]$newObjectProperties
```